# How to run Genymotion via terminal

Tags: command-line, android, execute-command

So I installed Genymotion and I used this website as a guide: https://cloud.genymotion.com/page/doc/. Unfortunately, when I do the last step it won't let me run the application.

Thank you. This is the error coming up in terminal:

```
./genymotion
bash: ./genymotion: Is a directory
```

Comment: `sudo chmod a+x ./genymotion`. That will do it.

Comment: you have to run it after switching to installation path. using **cd**

Comment: thank you @user245240 for your reply i typed it in but the application didnt open what should i do in this case?

Answer (score 5):

1st, you need to check the location where you have installed genymotion.

2nd, Supposing it to be default downloads folder. You can enter this folder by typing    these commands in the terminal:

```
$ sudo su
```

then you will be prompted for root password, then type

```
$ cd Downloads
```

here in the Downloads folder you can see the list of files typing `ls`

If you see `genymotion` directory then enter the directory typing `cd genymotion`  then type `./genymotion` and it will run the application.

You are good to go now.

In case your default installation directory is something else then enter that directory and follow the last 2 commands(`cd genymotion` and then `./genymotion`)

Let me know if there is any problem.